# Lotus Domino Designer - Java Log class: openAgentLog not working

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, ibm-domino

After running the code below, I cannot find the word "Action One" in the log under `log.nsf`, does anyone know what is the problem?

```
import lotus.domino.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

  public void NotesMain() {
    try {
      Session session = getSession();
      AgentContext agentContext = 
      session.getAgentContext();
      // (Your code goes here) 
      Log log = session.createLog("Agent Log");
      log.openAgentLog();
      log.logAction("Action one");
      log.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Agent log](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/de/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_OPENAGENTLOG_METHOD_JAVA.html) is visible in agent only:

> This method stores output in the log for the current agent and fails
>   if the program is not running as an agent. **To display an agent log,
>   select the agent and choose Agent - Log.**

In case you want to see log entries in log.nsf use `System.out.println(...)` instead. The agent has to run on server to see the entries in server's log.nsf.

Comment: Yes, your are correct, I overlook... but do you know how can I write the log to `log.nsf`?

Comment: I updated my answer - use `System.out.println(...)` and run agent scheduled on server or call it with runOnServer.

Comment: Be aware that the AgentLog has a size limit: only 64K text. Better use an ordinary NotesLog to a database (based on the AgentLog template).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the [OpenNTF project OpenLog](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenLog) to do your logging. It's an older project, but still supported.
Your log entries will be written in a separate log database, so your system log won't be polluted. Furthermore, the log entries contain more information (like agent name, username and stacktrace) to make it easier to debug your application.